# Upload Image by URL only

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, backbone.js, file-upload

I need to upload an external image when a user pastes the url into an input bar. I am using dropzone, jquery, and backbone. So I'm thinking dropzone to upload the image, but I don't exactly know how it would work without the user literally dropping the image onto the page from the page they get it from. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no way you can auto-upload files from user's PC. Upload from net is an easy job though.

Comment: is it some sort of security issue or something? If so, is there any documentation you can point me to?

Comment: you can't upload an external image, that would be a download... you can upload the url to the server or possibly download the image to the client.

Comment: Selecting any file on user's PC (without interaction) is a big security flow and that will never be allowed by browsers. I am not sure what do you exactly want.

Comment: @skobaljic: you can already use an <input type=file> to select any file on the local PC or network shared folders...

Comment: Yes, but user must click it and select.

Comment: please reread the question. the user's steps would be as follows: 1) paste url into an input tag, 2) click on upload button, 3) wait for image to upload to server. There's nothing that i can use like localstorage or anything else?

Comment: @skobaljic correct, all i want the user to do is paste a url into a form's input element. if there's any documentation that you guys know of out there that has explaining this specifically, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: You could use image drag/drop + for Chrome CTR+V using [this plugin](https://github.com/Rovak/InlineAttachment). I also saw other snippets, but CTR+V works only in Chrome.

Comment: Correction, it may work in FF too, look at [here](http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/)

Comment: **Just to get all the confusion out of the way:** I'm guessing you just want the same functionality that StackOverflow uses when you compose a question, right? If you insert an image, you can upload an external image from the web by pasting the URL.

Comment: don't remember ever using that, but what you're describing seems accurate.